# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session, I have tried my all possible solution

Tags: php, html, header

I tried some solution from internet, I put `session_start();` at first line, also try by using `@ob_start();` Any other solution???
My code is here:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('page.inc');  

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>site 1</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="universe, blog theme, black, website template, templatemo" />
<meta name="description" content="About Universe, Our Company, free website template" />
<link href="templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js" ></script>


</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedinuser']))
{
if (isset($_POST['Signin']))
{
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
if($username=='a')
$_SESSION['loggedinuser']=$username;
else
echo " the username or password you entered do not matchted ! ";

}
else
{
?>
 <form  method="post" action="index.php" >
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" > 
<input name="Signin" type="submit" value="Signin" />
</form>
<?

}
}
    else
    //something else
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here the error is:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/jasi/medu_quiz_22111_bl/index.php:1) in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/jasi/medu_quiz_22111_bl/index.php on line 2

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/jasi/medu_quiz_22111_bl/index.php:1) in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/jasi/medu_quiz_22111_bl/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: do u start the session in page.inc ?

Comment: Not actually, Could you please help me to find out what header information is going to browser before session_start(); ??? @vascowhite

Comment: No, page.inf has some function only.  @faizphp

Comment: did u use like this "@ob_start();" ? or ob_start(); ?

Comment: @user3129375 Have you read and tried everything in the question I linked to? Your answer is in there somewhere. This question is, without doubt, a duplicate of that.

Comment: I used both @faizphp

Comment: I tried to try all solutions , but in my case I could not find out my problem , I cant cope with your solution.... @vascowhite

Comment: its just a warning message better u put error_reporting(0) and go head ..

Comment: actually I am doing this (error_reporting(0);) from last 5 month. but suddenly today it stops creating session and not executing following codes that should execute after session creation. Thus I am trying to find out. @faizphp

Comment: did u check with phpinfo() ? is ur Session Support is enabled ?

Comment: Yes , I did it. even Opera showing this error but creating session also. but in mozilla and google chrome does not creating session. @faizphp

Comment: ok comment the line session_start() and check again!! do u got error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66546/discussion-between-faizphp-and-user3129375).

Comment: <?php
@ob_start();
session_start();
?> use lke this

Comment: use this if(session_status()!=PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) session_start()..

Comment: Make sure there is absolutely no whitespace before <?php

Put session_start() before ob_start() instead of after it.

If that fails, try commenting out the session_start() as one of your includes might already be starting the session, like so:  /** session_start(); **/

Comment: I have already done all of this. :-(

Comment: :( without ur code i dont know how to find that

Answer (score 1):

Check whitespaces before `<?php`, ensure that the `<?php` is the first character, not tabbed or spaced.

Comment: This is most likely the issue.

Comment: ya, is it a problem for this issue ??

Comment: Session is working fine, I tried the code, on opera it is a caching issue

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and all works fine, I copied pasted it as is and the form is showing normal

even submitted the form twice once with the correct value and form disappeared and once with the wrong value and the message that it is a wrong value

if you have placed some white space before :

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        ....
        ?>
```

That might produce an error, nothing should come before the session_start() part, maybe you have note created the page: page.inc and that is doing the damage

This is the new code I tried, and these are step you can take:

I have checked it with opera, yes at first it was not showing, but with a heavy refresh it did show, try to do a no caching mechanism, by maybe sending it to page with a random id, this will clear the cache, the problem is not session in opera, the session is working, it is in caching,

Refresh your opera and you will, I took the address and copied it into another tab on opera, and the session showed, This is the complete copy on my version:

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        require_once('page.inc');  

        ?>

        ........

        <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedinuser']))
        {
            if (isset($_POST['Signin']))
            {
                $username=$_REQUEST['username'];
                if($username=='a')
                $_SESSION['loggedinuser']=$username;
                else
                echo " the username or password you entered do not matchted ! ";

            }
            else
            {
            ?>
             <form  method="post" action="index.php" >
                    ......
            </form>
            <?

            }
        }
        else if(isset($_SESSION['loggedinuser']))
        {
                $ses = $_SESSION['loggedinuser'];
                echo "LINE 47 session is $ses ";
        }
        else
        {
            $ses2 = $_SESSION['loggedinuser'];
            echo "LINE 51 session is $ses2 ";

        }
        ?>

            </body>
            </html>
```

This produces:

Line 2 included a page LINE 47 session is a 56

page.inc

```
        <?php
        echo " Line 2 included  a page ";
        ?>
```

Comment: This code is running from 5 month, although the warning was seen. but suddenly it stops to create session......I cant find out the problem.....

Comment: Your code on Line 44:


        else
 {
    

         I have added this :

        else
 {
     $ses = $_SESSION['loggedinuser'];
  echo "session is $ses ";
 
 }

It is displaying correctly:

 session is a

Comment: Yes it is happening for Opera for me. but not for Mozilla and google chrome !! really its such a problem I have never faced !!

Comment: I have checked it with opera, yes at first it was not showing, but with a heavy refresh it did show, try to do a no caching mechanism, by maybe sending it to page with a random id, this will clear the cache, the problem is not session inopera, the session is working, it is in caching, refresh your opera and you will, I took the address and copied it into another tab on opera, and the session showed, This is the complete copy on my version, I will add on the answer, I appreciate if you mark my question as useful or the right answer